# Create Json from scala object with List

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I need to create a Json with 2 elements. The First element is a List and the second element is simple key-value pair.
My output looks as follows:

```
"{
  "tables":[
  {"table": "sn: 2134"},
  {"table": "sn: 5676"},
  {"table": "sn: 4564"},
  ],
  "paid": 219
  }"
```

In the example , the first element is `tables` which is List of `table`. The second element is `paid`.

I tried it using `play.api.libs.json` lib , but stuck while adding second element.

My code looks as follows:

```
 case class Input(table:String){
    override def toString = s""""table" : "sn: $table""""
  }
implicit val userFormat = Json.format[Input]
val inputsSeq = Seq(Input(table1),Input(table2),Input(table3))
val users = Json.obj("tables" -> inputsSeq)
println(users)
```

This code print Json as :

```
 "{
      "tables":[
      {"table": "sn: 2134"},
      {"table": "sn: 5676"},
      {"table": "sn: 4564"},
      ]
}
```

I am not sure, how to add the second element in this json. any suggestion how to 
resolve this.

Comment: wouldn't `Json.obj("tables" -> inputsSeq, "paid" -> 219)` do the trick?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks.. that did it. Does Json.obj() expects a map?

Comment: I override tostring() method of Input case class , to add "sn:" string when it is converted to Json. But following this method , i see "sn:" is not added when object is converted to Json. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

`Json.obj` accepts multiple pairs of `(String, JsValueWrapper)` as its arguments:

```
object Json {
  ...
  def obj(fields: (String, JsValueWrapper)*): JsObject = JsObject(fields.map(f => (f._1, f._2.asInstanceOf[JsValueWrapperImpl].field)))
  ...
}
```

So you can add both elements like this:

```
val users = Json.obj("tables" -> inputsSeq, "paid" -> 219)
```

Comment: No, I didnt know how to add it. My purpose was to create a scala object which has both paid and table variable. And when i convert it to Json , it would be generated.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question. I have edited the answer

Comment: I override tostring() method of Input case class , to add "sn:" string when it is converted to Json. But following this method , i see "sn:" is not added when object is converted to Json. Am i missing anything here?